# Parameterized UPDATE DON'T modiff any row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, parameterized

i have been trying to make an update using parameters like that

`String whereClause = KEY_FIELD_CODE + “= ?” String whereArgs[] ={“123456″}`

But nothing works just update 0 rows, even if the rows who matches with the field exists. But the result change when i set the update statement like this:

`String whereClause = KEY_FIELD_CODE + “= 123456″ 
String whereArgs[] =null`

Does anyone knows why or in which cases this happens?. and the most important thing is how to fix that. Note: in this table im using a FTS3 to make full text search.. and i know the importance using parameterized querys, i would like to use it and not concatenating params.

Thanks

```
for(Customer client : clients){

            Log.v(TAG, "Preparing..........");
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(FData.KEY_CLIENT_CODE,   client.getCode());
            values.put(FData.KEY_CLIENT_ZONE,   client.getZone());
            values.put(FData.KEY_CLIENT_NAME,   client.getName());
            values.put(FData.KEY_CLIENT_CREDIT, client.getCredit());
            values.put(FData.KEY_CLIENT_ESTATE, client.getEstate());
            values.put(FData.KEY_CLIENT_ENTRY,  client.getEntry());

            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CPFertica.CLIENTS_URI, client.getCode());
            if(exists(uri)){
                Log.v(TAG, "Updating..........");
                values.remove(FData.KEY_CLIENT_CODE);
                String[] whereArgs = new String[]{client.getCode()+""};
                String whereClause = FData.KEY_CLIENT_CODE + "=" + client.getCode();
                _contentResolver.update(uri, values, whereClause, null);
            }else{
                Log.v(TAG, "Inserting..........");
                _contentResolver.insert(uri, values);
            }
```

Table Structure

`private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_CLIENTS = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + 
            DB_TABLE_CLIENTS + " USING fts3 ( "+
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  " +
            KEY_CLIENT_CODE     + " INTEGER UNIQUE, " +
            KEY_CLIENT_ZONE     + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_CLIENT_NAME     + " TEXT, " + 
            KEY_CLIENT_ESTATE   + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_CLIENT_CREDIT   + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_CLIENT_TAX      + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_CLIENT_ENTRY    + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_CLIENT_PRICE    + " TEXT);";`

Comment: Show the table definition.

Comment: there is @CL. that is the Table Structure which holds the regs i need to update.

Comment: Is it `KEY_FIELD_CODE` or `KEY_CLIENT_CODE` or `KEY_CLIENTE_CODIGO`?

Comment: @CL. Just KEY_CLIENT_CODE, i made a mistake trying to explain the the situation.

Answer (score 1):

In a virtual table, [affinities](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) do not necessarily work as in normal tables.
The values in the INTEGER column are compared as numbers, so the string `"123456"` does never compare equal with any of them.

`whereArgs` works only with strings. (This is a design bug of the Android database API.)
When using integers, insert them directly into the SQL string.

Please note that FTS tables store all their columns as plain strings; PRIMARY KEY, AUTOINCREMENT, and UNIQUE are ignored (and lookups on the code columns are slow if you do not use an FTS lookup).
If you want to have an (autoincrementing) numeric ID column, you must use the [internal rowid column](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3).

Comment: Ok i see, but as long as i use a Content Provider i have to keep using the "_id" column. Now i change to use the "rowid" instead.Do you consider proper assign the value to "rowid" instead let db assign it?

Comment: You can always do `SELECT rowid AS _id, ...`. Whether you want specific `rowid` values or not depends on DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **replace** statement, it will add new row to db if it does not exist else update the row.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBUtils.KEY_ID, data.getDoctorId());
        values.put(DBUtils.KEY_FIRST_NAME, data.getFirstName());
        values.put(DBUtils.KEY_LAST_NAME, data.getLastName());
        count = db.replace(DBUtils.TABLE_USER, null, values);
```

Or try this thing

where clause ==> DBUtils.KEY_ID + "=?"
where arges ==> new String[] { String.valueOf(id))